# Is there a LaTeX package for easy indentation?

Tags: indentation

Sometimes I need to indent several lines and display math text.

For example, to make some semantic proofs in logic.

Here is an example of how I'm currently doing indent

```tex
Suppose $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{KB}$

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
Then

\setlength\parindent{48pt}
$\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,X)} \to \neg \text{P(b,X)}$

$\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,n)}$

Therefore

\setlength\parindent{72pt}
$\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{P(b,n)} $

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
Also,

\setlength\parindent{48pt}
$\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{ P(X, n)} \to \neg \text{E(X)}$
```

Pretty bad, because I have to use `\setlength\parindent{24pt}` every time I
need to change indentation. Here is the result I need:

```
Suppose J ⊨ KB
    Then
        J ⊨ P(a,X) → ¬ P(b,X)
        J ⊨ P(a,n)
        Therefore
            J ⊨ ¬ P(b,n)
    Also,
        J ⊨ ¬ P(X,n) → ¬ E(X)
```

I wish I could have this indentation using only tabs, just like in plain text.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible,keepspaces,mathescape}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Suppose $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{KB}$
    Then
        $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,X)} \to \neg \text{P(b,X)}$
        $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,n)}$
        Therefore
            $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{P(b,n)} $
    Also,
        $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{ P(X, n)} \to \neg \text{E(X)}$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sounds great

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the rare cases¹ where LaTeX's much ignored `tabbing` environment makes sense.

Here's an example of this for your code:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{24pt}\=\hspace{24pt}\=\hspace{24pt}\kill % ❶
Suppose $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{KB}$\\
\> Then \\ % ❷
\> \> $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,X)} \to \neg \text{P(b,X)}$\\
\> \> $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \text{P(a,n)}$\\
\> \> Therefore\\
\> \> \> $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{P(b,n)} $ \\
\> Also, \\
\> \> $\mathfrak{J} \vDash \neg \text{ P(X, n)} \to \neg \text{E(X)}$
\end{tabbing}
```

We start out by setting our ``tab stops'' ❶. Each `\=` command² sets a tab stop and `\kill` at the end of the line tells LaTeX to not actually set the text specified.

Then we use `\>` to tab to each tab stop in turn using `\\` to start a new line ❷.

In my deleted chapter, I had suggested `tabbing` as a means to do three things that have better solutions now: typesetting algorithms, pretty-printing code³ and multi-page tables, but for your case it's a pretty good fit.⁴

---

1. Rare enough that I took out the chapter on `tabbing` from my LaTeX book.
2. The `tabbing` environment steals some of the accent commands for its own use. As a result, you need to use `\a=`, `\a'` and `` \a` `` to get the macron, acute and grave accents.
3. Although I have to say that I don't like the aesthetics of the default styling of the `listings` package.
4. Another option that would be much more work would be to create a custom algorithm type with the `algorithmicx` package, but I suspect that would be more work than it's worth (and definitely more work than I care to do for a tex.se answer). I'd note that `algorithmicx` manages its indentation through subtly hidden nested `list` environments.

Comment: It seems like a similar approach would be to use `\newcommand*{\tabs}[1]{\hspace{\tabs\parindent}}`, and then you wouldn't need to worry about the tabbing environment.

Comment: THanks for the answer!

Comment: @Teepeemm The tabbing environment provides some fancy abilities that aren't possible with that approach, for example, you can set the tab stops using a text template, or reset them mid-listing. The whole thing is rather clever, but doesn't really fit in well with the rest of LaTeX in some ways. (Your `\newcommand` won't work by the way.)